# How can I get the distance between 2 elements (middle point)?

Tags: jquery, math

i need your help! I have a random amount of divs placed between themselves.

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">Item description</div>
    <div class="item">Item description</div>
    <div class="item">Item description</div>
    <div class="item">Item description</div>
</div>
```

Each of the has a different height and i have to calculate the distance between them. It is really important that the distance is from each middle point of each item.

Thanks in advance!

Maybe my image will it explain better than my horrible english :) 
[image]

Comment: Please explain... Are all the items distanced equally?

Comment: No because each of them has a different height, so the distance cant be equal each time

Comment: Oh and sorry there is no really a distance between themselves!!!! i forgot! They touch each other

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe _Maybe my image will explain it better_? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my gosh! Sometimes it is easier than you might think!

```
var currentCenterPoint = $('.current').outerHeight() / 2;
var nextCenterPoint = $('.current').next().outerHeight() / 2;

var amount = (currentCenterPoint + nextCenterPoint);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `offset` method:

```
var $items = $('.item');
var fh = $items.eq(0).height();
var sh = $items.eq(1).height();
var first = $items.eq(0).offset().top + fh;
var two = $items.eq(1).offset().top;

var distance  = (two - first) + (fh/2) + (sh/2) ;
```

Comment: You're missing a crucial factor: The height of the boxes.

Comment: But then i have not the distance from middle to middle?!

Comment: Well, still not quite. OP wanted to have the distance between the central points of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div>` try `<ul>` with `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/imefon/2/edit)*

```
$('.item').each(function(){
  
  if( $(this).next().is('.item') ){    
       var myHalf = $(this).outerHeight(true)/2;
       var nextHalf = $(this).next('.item').outerHeight(true)/2;
       $(this).text('distance in between: '+ (myHalf+nextHalf) ); // TEST  
  }
                  
});
```