# Measure distance between two HTML elements' centers

Tags: javascript, html, distance

If I have HTML elements as follows:

```
<div id="x"></div>

<div id="y" style="margin-left:100px;"></div>
```

...how do I find the distance between them in pixels using JavaScript?

Comment: your markup is invalid, but nevertheless - [calculate](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) absolute positions of the elements and use the [formula](http://cs.selu.edu/~rbyrd/math/distance/) to find out the distance.

Comment: You don't want to use jQuery, do you?

Comment: no, i dont. I wanna stick with standards as much as possible. :)

Comment: Well, jQuery `offset()` also uses `getBoundingClientRect()`. The code below makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the distance between 2 elements (middle point)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133049/how-can-i-get-the-distance-between-2-elements-middle-point)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Get their positions, and use the Pythagorean Theorem to determine the distance between them...

```
 function getPositionAtCenter(element) {
   const {top, left, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
     x: left + width / 2,
     y: top + height / 2
   };
 }

function getDistanceBetweenElements(a, b) {
  const aPosition = getPositionAtCenter(a);
  const bPosition = getPositionAtCenter(b);

  return Math.hypot(aPosition.x - bPosition.x, aPosition.y - bPosition.y);  
}

const distance = getDistanceBetweenElements(
  document.getElementById("x"),
  document.getElementById("y")
);
```

If you browser doesn't support `Math.hypot()`, you can use instead:

```
Math.sqrt(
  Math.pow(aPosition.x - bPosition.x, 2) + 
  Math.pow(aPosition.y - bPosition.y, 2) 
);
```

The Pythagorean Theorem relates to the relationship between the sides of a right-angled triangle.

[image: Pythagorean Theorem]

The elements are plotted on a [Cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) (with origin in top left), so you can imagine a right-angled triangle between the elements' coordinates (the unknown side is the hypotenuse).

You can modify the equation to get the value of `c` by getting the square root of the other side.

[image: Distance equation]

Then, you simply plug the values in (the `x` and `y` are the differences between the elements once their centers are determined) and you will find the length of the hypotenuse, which is the distance between the elements.

Comment: That holds if "position" is defined as the coordinates of the left top corner. I think using the center point is more accurate.

Comment: @Amberlamps Sure, if that's what the OP wants (they didn't mention that requirement), then they can adjust it (I'll update the answer too).

Comment: does your current answer give the distance between the 2 centers ?

Comment: now does your answer give the distance between centers? and are there any conditions for it to work or something??

Comment: Yup, it works! I accepted your answer and also plus voted! Thanks a lot for all your help! @alex

Comment: @alex awesome !

Comment: You can use Math.hypot() nowadays to clean things up a bit. Also, can I get a sticker for the Pythagorean Theorem so I can put it on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

as far as div's are now empty, the basic idea is to measure the distance between their left top corners

```
distX = y.offsetLeft - x.offsetLeft;
distY = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
alert(Math.floor(distance));
```

but you have to substract first `div`'s height and width, if you put something inside. This method has some issues with support and border width of elements in different browsers.

anyway take a look at **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/EY6Rk/)**

Note, that even with content (if you don't change it with css) divs will be 100% width, so if you want just to measure `br`'s height use:

```
distance = = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
```