# Distance between elements in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a planetarium in HTML/CSS/jQuery/JS, and there is something I don't really manage to do.

I have been searching for something similar and I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628456/measure-distance-between-two-html-elements-centers) which corresponds the most to what I am looking for.

Basically, my point is to represent the Solar system (most of it) in a plan (horizontally), and the user would only scroll to the right to see the planets, etc. There is no vertical scrolling.

I have created a div, which includes another div named "point" (width: 1px, height: 1px). My point is to calculate the distance between the div "point" and the center of my sun (div named "sun") when the user is scrolling (in real time).

Could you please help me with this?

Cheers.

Comment: So can we see your sun and planets..? or are we supposed to create our own solar system to solve the issue..?

Comment: too many points to be of any point and thus the negative reputation point..

Comment: Sorry, you can find it [here](http://planetarium.clockwork-robot.fr)

There are many things that need to be fixed, others to be added/improved. It is still under construction and far from being finished.

Comment: Please let us know what you have done so far (javascript code which tries to calculate the distance).

Comment: I bet i made lots of mistakes, beside the scale of the sun. http://jsfiddle.net/rj6h5/1/ but i think it's rather entertaining.

Comment: @Leo Why don't you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sun = $("#sun").position(), point = $("point").position();
var dx = sun.x - point.x, dy = sun.y - point.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

Comment: Isn't `position` a function? I believe it should have parentheses appended to it (`position()`).