# Getting the nearest positioned ancestor of an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

According to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp,

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

How can I get the nearest positioned ancestor of an Element, in either vanilla Javascript or JQuery?

---

What about offsetParent()? https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/

> **Description:** *Get the closest ancestor element that is positioned.*

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find the closest parent element in the DOM tree that has a `position` of anything other than `static`? Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: I am saying that I want to get the element an 'element with position: absolute' is relative positioned to.

Comment: In that case @TemaniAfif just answered with the solution :)

Answer (score 7):

You can test if the position is static of the parent, if not you continue until your reach the first ancestor with position different from static.

Here is a simplified code that you can adjust:

```js
$('.box').each(function() {
  var p = $(this).parent();
  while (p && p.css('position') === 'static') {
    p = p.parent();
  }
  console.log(p.attr('class'));
})
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
}

.f2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f1">
  <div class="f2">
    <div class="f3">
      <div class="box"> <!-- This one relative to f2 -->
        <div class="box"> <!-- This one relative to box -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="f1">
  <div class="f2">
    <div class="f3" style="position:absolute;">
      <div class="box"> <!-- This one relative to f3 -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend adding one more condition, in case the loop reaches the "document" (above the "html" element) and the position check errors, so basically `while (p && p.parent()[0].nodeType === 1 && p.css('position') === 'static')` or `while (p && p.parent().prop('nodeType') === 1 && p.css('position') === 'static')`

Answer (score 1):

Edit : I was assuming you were looking for distance bewteen two elements. @TemaniAfif has the right answer

---

You could navigate the tree of ancestors using `parentNode` and compare the `offsetTop` of each to the `offsetTop` of the element at hand. if all you are interested in is the Y distance.

On the other hand if you need the full distance while accounting for X and Y, you could use the method described here

[Measure distance between two HTML elements' centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628456/measure-distance-between-two-html-elements-centers)

Comment: This is about measuring the literal distance in pixels, whereas the OP seems to be wanting to simply get a reference to the parent which is governing the positioning of the absolute element - `How can I get the nearest positioned ancestor of an Element`

Answer (score 1):

The vanilla JavaScript solution: use `HTMLElement` property [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent)

```
document.querySelector('#myElementID').offsetParent
```

Note: There are some special cases, where `offsetParent` is `null`. More details in the linked documentation.