# jQuery - Find space between elements by targeting element type

Tags: jquery

I need to find out the space between each element. Let's space between X and Y, Y and Z, and ...

By using below code, I can able to get the same by using its id or class

```
<a href="#" id="x">X</a>
<a href="#" id="y" style="margin-left:100px;">Y</a>
<div class="distance">Total distance</div>

distX = y.offsetLeft - x.offsetLeft;
distY = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
jQuery('.distance').html('Distance: ' + Math.floor(distance) + 'px');
```

I am getting the output as: `Distance: 116px` which is correct.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xe1328nv/1/

Thanks to @vladkras for the first solution [Measure distance between two HTML elements' centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628456/measure-distance-between-two-html-elements-centers)

But in my case, anchor tags comes dynamically where I cannot assign the class id.

How can I find out the space between each element in below case?

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="#">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
```

Out put should be like below:

```
Space between Link 1 & Link 2 = ???
Space between Link 2 & Link 3 = ???
Space between Link 3 & Link 4 = ???
Space between Link 4 & Link 5 = ???
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dr4kqxzc/

Comment: In what context? Could you just click the elements (links) and need the space between them? Or is it the Fiddle you gave accurate to your situation?

Comment: Btw: No need to use external code sites like JSFiddle, just create a snippet right here. It's preferrable.

Comment: Have you checked the answers you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's commented in the code. Let me know if any questions arise.

```js
$('.social-links a').each(function() {
  //alert($(this).attr('href'));
  var popupText = $(this).attr('data-social');
  $(this).append('<div class="popup-text">' + popupText + '</div>');
});

// get the NodeList of links
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.social-links a');

// define the variables we need
let distance;
let distanceHtml = '';
let distX;
let distY;

// iterate over the NodeList
for (let i = 0; i < links.length - 1; i++) {
  distX = links[i + 1].offsetLeft - links[i].offsetLeft;
  distY = links[i + 1].offsetTop - links[i].offsetTop;
  distance = Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distY * distY);
  // using a template literal here (ES6)
  distanceHtml += `Space between Link ${i+1} &amp; Link ${i+2} = ${Math.floor(distance)}px<br />`;
}

document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = distanceHtml;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.main-div {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 120px 20px 10px 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.main-div a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.main-div a .popup-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.popup-text:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 34px;
}

#distance {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="social-links">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Facebook"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-20.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Twitter"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-20.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Youtube"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/youtube_circle_color-20.png" alt="Youtube" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Linkedin"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-20.png" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="distance"></div>
```

I haven't used jQuery (except the part I copied from your fiddle) because it's unnecessary here (as for most things). I prefer to use vanilla Javascript for just about anything.

Comment: Thanks for your great support. I am accepting and upvoting your answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You already have the code for create a generic function...

All you have to do is iterate inside each elements and check that there's a next element to compare with.

```js
function spaceBetween(x,y,namex="x",namey="y"){
  distX = y.offsetLeft - x.offsetLeft;
  distY = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
  distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
  $('.distance').append('Distance ('+namex+' - '+namey+'): ' + Math.floor(distance) + 'px <br>');
}

var x = $('#x')[0];
var y = $('#y')[0];

spaceBetween(x,y)

 $(".random-elements a").each(function(i){
  if($(this).next()[0] !== undefined){
    var x = $(this);
    var y = $(this).next();
    spaceBetween(x[0],y[0],x.html(),y.html())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="x">X</a>
<a href="#" id="y" style="margin-left:100px;">Y</a>

<div class="random-elements">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div class="distance"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__link');
  const offsets = [...elements].map((elem, indx, arr) => {
    const elemMarginLeft = window.getComputedStyle(elem).marginLeft.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0];
    const elemUnit = window.getComputedStyle(elem).marginLeft.match(/[^0-9]+/g)[0];
    const elemOffset = indx === 0 ? 0 : elemMarginLeft * indx;

    return indx === 0 ? `` : `Space between ${arr[indx - 1].text} & ${elem.text} = ${elemOffset}${elemUnit}`;
  }).join('<br/>');

  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = offsets
});
```

```css
.wrapper { background-color:cornflowerblue; padding: 15px; }
.wrapper__link { background-color: aqua; padding:5px; margin-left: 15px; }
.wrapper__link--margin-left-50 { margin-left: 50px } 
.wrapper__link--margin-left-100 { margin-left: 100px } 

.result { margin-top: 10px }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="wrapper__link" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a class="wrapper__link" href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a class="wrapper__link wrapper__link--margin-left-50" href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a class="wrapper__link" href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a class="wrapper__link wrapper__link--margin-left-100" href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You have any reference that a `NodeList` can use rest spread `[...elements]`?

Comment: [hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9)