# Drawing arrows above HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an html table and I want to draw an arrow from one cell to an other cell. For example like this:

[image: arrow-above-html-table]

How could this be done?

Example HTML:

```
<html>

 <body>

<table>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td id="end">9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td id="start">0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>


</body>

</html>
```

If you resize the browser, the arrow should stay on the (new) start/end position.

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself yet? Sounds like this could be done using javascript and css

Comment: @AlexanderKludt in this case I have no clue. I could not find useful hints with my favorite search engine.

Comment: Can we assume that all cells are equal in height and width like in the example?

Comment: ...If also aspect ratio is known it can be done with just css (based on cell x,y position) and controlled by js function acting on css vars. To use selectors then its context must be explored to guess those coordinates in the function.

Not knowing aspect ratio I'm still thinking on it...

Comment: @bitifet could you detect aspect ratio by JS?

Comment: @guettli of course! but then it won't be a pure CSS solution (even almost) you then will need to detect size changes and recalculate and inject kinda aspect_ratio css var. It is plausible, but not as wonderful as a pure css solution ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a bit of JavasSript and CSS you can achieve this without canvas or SVG. Here is an example:

```js
function getPosition(el) {
   return {
     x: el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth / 2,
     y: el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight / 2
   };
 }

 function getDistance(a, b) {
   const from = getPosition(a);
   const to = getPosition(b);

   return {
   //https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628488/529024
     distance: Math.hypot(from.x - to.x, from.y - to.y),
     angle: Math.atan2(to.x - from.x, from.y - to.y) * 180 / Math.PI,
     position: {
       start: from,
       end: to
     }
   }
 }

function init(){
// Get values and elements then set style
 const values = getDistance(
   document.getElementById("start"),
   document.getElementById("end")
 );
 
 
 let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
 let arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
 let bottom = wrapper.offsetHeight - values.position.start.y;
 arrow.style.height = values.distance + "px";
 arrow.style.transform = `rotate(${values.angle}deg)`;
 arrow.style.bottom = bottom + "px";
 arrow.style.left = values.position.start.x + "px";
}

init();

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
 init();
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}

#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#arrow::before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid red;
    content: "";
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='arrow'></div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td >0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td id="end">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="start">0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug: Your arrow is different. It ends at the first zero.

Comment: I changed the values. I updated the sample now to reflect your example.

Comment: If I use `ctrl -` (decrease size) the arrow looses the ending position.

Answer (score 5):

You can use my solution not complete draw arrow yet, 
let create a canvas and draw a line from two points, based on calculate of start and end point.

```
Example running: https://jsfiddle.net/tabvn/uk7hsj3a
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td id="end">9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="start">0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var table = document.getElementById('my-table')
  var startElement = document.getElementById('start')
  var endElement = document.getElementById('end')

  var startPoint = {x: startElement.offsetLeft + table.offsetLeft, y: startElement.offsetTop + table.offsetTop}
  var endPoint = {x: endElement.offsetLeft + table.offsetLeft, y: endElement.offsetTop + table.offsetTop}
  
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = table.clientWidth
  canvas.height = table.clientHeight
  canvas.style.position = 'absolute'
  canvas.style.top = startPoint.y < endPoint.y ? startPoint.y + 'px' : endPoint.y + 'px'
  canvas.style.left = startPoint.x < endPoint.x ? startPoint.x + 'px' : endPoint.x + 'px'

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.moveTo(startPoint.x - (startElement.clientWidth / 2), startPoint.y)
  ctx.lineTo(endPoint.x - (endElement.clientWidth / 2), endPoint.y)
  ctx.stroke()
  document.body.insertBefore(canvas, table, 30)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I resize the screen (ctrl + and ctrl -), then the red line loses the position.

Comment: so add resize we could group solution in a function, and then you can listen window resize and call again render canvas.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it:
The svg element uses the size of the table for the viewBox value.
You are calculating the size and the position of the cells you need to correlate and use this position to draw the line. A marker is used for the tip of the arrow.

Please resize the window:

```js
let cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("td"));
// index of cells to be correlated
let n1 = 90;
let n2 = 9;
// a function to draw the arrow
function drawArrow(){
//get the size of the table
let size = theTable.getBoundingClientRect();
//set the viewBox attribute for the svg element
theSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${size.width} ${size.height}`)
//get the size and the position of the cells
let c1 = cells[n1].getBoundingClientRect();
let c2 = cells[n2].getBoundingClientRect();
//set the x1, y1, x2,y2 attributes of the line
theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"x1",`${c1.left + c1.width/2}`);
theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"y1",`${c1.top + c1.height/2}`);
theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"x2",`${c2.left + c2.width/2}`);
theLine.setAttributeNS(null,"y2",`${c2.top + c1.height/2}`); 
}


drawArrow()


window.setTimeout(function() {
  drawArrow()
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawArrow, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table,svg{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

svg{background:rgba(0,0, 255,.5)}
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td id="end">9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
 <tr><td id="start">0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><tr>
</table>

<svg id="theSVG">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="12" refX="8" refY="6" orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 8 6 L 0 12" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line id="theLine" marker-end="url(#arrow)" stroke="black" />  
</svg>
```

## UPDATE:

Since someone commented that on resize the arrow is losing it's position I am adding a gif:

[image]

Comment: If I resize the screen (ctrl + and ctrl -) then the arrow loses the position.

Comment: I don't think so: I've added a gif

Comment: Unfortunately the start position of the arrow lost position after `ctrl +` (after `ctrl -`) https://imgur.com/8xbEAK2   Iuse Chromium 78.0.3904.70

Answer (score 4):

Javascript solution:

```js
drawLine();

function drawLine () {
  var table = document.getElementById('my-table')
  var startElement = document.getElementById('start')
  var endElement = document.getElementById('end')

  let arrowRadius = 10;

  let xStart = null;
  let xEnd = null;
  if (startElement.offsetLeft > endElement.offsetLeft) {
    xStart = startElement.offsetLeft + (arrowRadius/2);//to add padding just add more wherever theres this pattern 
    xEnd = endElement.offsetLeft + endElement.offsetWidth / 2;
  } else if (startElement.offsetLeft < endElement.offsetLeft) {
    xStart = startElement.offsetLeft + startElement.offsetWidth - (arrowRadius/2);
    xEnd = endElement.offsetLeft;
  } else {
    xStart = startElement.offsetLeft + startElement.offsetWidth / 2;
    xEnd = endElement.offsetLeft + endElement.offsetWidth / 2;
  }

  let yStart = null;
  let yEnd = null;
  if (startElement.offsetTop > endElement.offsetTop) {
    yStart = startElement.offsetTop + (arrowRadius/2);
    yEnd = endElement.offsetTop + endElement.offsetHeight + (arrowRadius/2);
  } else if (startElement.offsetTop < endElement.offsetTop) {
    yStart = startElement.offsetTop + startElement.offsetHeight - (arrowRadius/2);
    yEnd = endElement.offsetTop - (arrowRadius/2);
  } else {
    yStart = startElement.offsetTop + startElement.offsetHeight / 2;
    yEnd = endElement.offsetTop + endElement.offsetHeight / 2;
  }

  let coordBegin = {
    x: xStart,
    y: yStart
  };
  let coordEnd = {
    x: xEnd,
    y: yEnd
  };

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = table.offsetWidth
  canvas.height = table.offsetHeight
  canvas.style.position = 'absolute'

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  drawArrowhead(ctx, coordBegin, coordEnd, arrowRadius);
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.moveTo(coordBegin.x, coordBegin.y)
  ctx.lineTo(coordEnd.x, coordEnd.y)
  ctx.stroke()

  document.body.insertBefore(canvas, table)
}




function drawArrowhead(context, from, to, radius) {
    var x_center = to.x;
    var y_center = to.y;

    var angle;
    var x;
    var y;

    context.beginPath();

    angle = Math.atan2(to.y - from.y, to.x - from.x)
    x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + x_center;
    y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + y_center;

    context.moveTo(x, y);

    angle += (1.0/3.0) * (2 * Math.PI)
    x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + x_center;
    y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + y_center;

    context.lineTo(x, y);

    angle += (1.0/3.0) * (2 * Math.PI)
    x = radius *Math.cos(angle) + x_center;
    y = radius *Math.sin(angle) + y_center;

    context.lineTo(x, y);

    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fill();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td id="end">9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="start">0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use chrome and the red line goes downward starting at the first "2".

Comment: As is supposed too, since the id's are at those positions

Comment: @guettli it works for every position just switch the id's and it has into account the start and end position so it draws the arrow with proper alignment

Comment: I updated your answer. The arrow points to the first "9" now, like in the question. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an SVG element and css styles for absolute position overlaying your table. And get the start and end point by JavaScript DOM API like `getBoundingClientRect()`

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-arrow-between-elements?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) is a demo. (Made with Angular, but you can use it everywhere. Pure JavaScript example see below.)

```
const startElement = document.querySelector('#start');
const endElement = document.querySelector('#end');

const startRect = startElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const endRect = endElement.getBoundingClientRect();

const startX = startRect.right;
const startY = startRect.top;

const endX = endRect.left;
const endY = endRect.bottom;
```

You can change the start and end dynamically. You only have to reinvoke the method to get the positions. Note that I use left, top, right, button to place the arrow on the edge of the element. You could compute the center point or the edge by comparing the both positions.

And you have to place the svg over the table. You can do this by set css `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0`. But note, that your parent should also have the `position` attribute. e.g. `position: relative`.

Update: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-arrow-between-elements?embed=1&file=index.html) is a pure JavaScript demo. Click on the left to view all files and select index.js to view the JS stuff. (like in VS Code).

Complete code:

```html
<table style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td id="end">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="start">0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>

    <svg style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1">
        <defs>
            <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="5" refY="3" orient="auto"
                markerUnits="strokeWidth" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
            </marker>
        </defs>

        <line id="svg-line" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="5"
            marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
    </svg>
</table>
<script>
const svgLine = document.querySelector('#svg-line');

const startElement = document.querySelector("#start");
const endElement = document.querySelector("#end");

const startRect = startElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const endRect = endElement.getBoundingClientRect();


const startX = startRect.right;
const startY = startRect.top;

const endX = endRect.left;
const endY = endRect.bottom;

svgLine.setAttribute('x1', startX);
svgLine.setAttribute('y1', startY);
svgLine.setAttribute('x2', endX);
svgLine.setAttribute('y2', endY);
</script>
```

Just copy the code above in a new empty html file and run it in your browser.

Btw. You can also do this with a canvas. (alternative for svg)

Comment: You need a complete implementation here and not a third party site. External links go dead over time and will make your answer useless. The code you show here is incomplete. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the table in a div and give a property, position: relative
Then write HTML for the arrow (use an image if you want to) and give it a property of absolute and then style it as you want using, top, left, right..

Read more about position properties here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Your answer is correct. But still something is missing. Using an image for the image does work well. It does not scale nicely.

Comment: The question is tagged "svg" and he asks how to "draw" the arrow so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: use SVG, scaling will not be a lot of issue