# How To Calculate Distance JavaScript Between Elements Inside A Flex Container Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

i need to calculate margin left and right to children of an flex item

```
<div class="sec images" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
  <img src="images/en_mb-mega-01.png" alt="">
  <img src="images/en_mb-mega-03.png" alt="">
  <img src="images/en_mb-mega-04.png" alt="">
</div>
```

i tried  to loop trough children but it only gives me the width of the child
i need the width and margins

**Note**

```
$(element).width()
```

didn't worked

```
main.js file :
  var current_item_children = current_item.children();

$.each(current_item_children, function () {
  var this_item = $(this);
  children.push(
    {
      width: this_item.width(),
      outerWidth:this_item.outerWidth(false),
      height: this_item.height(),

    }
  );
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: Add your js code too

Comment: @rajanbhadauria i added js code, please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance between first and second element in pixel:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.containt')[1].getBoundingClientRect().left - document.querySelectorAll('.containt')[0].clientWidth);

})
```

```css
.container {

  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.containt {

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
<div class="containt">

</div>
<div class="containt">

</div>
<div class="containt">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is where i found how to measure distance between elements
[Measure distance between two HTML elements' centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628456/measure-distance-between-two-html-elements-centers)

```js
 function getPositionAtCenter(element) {
   const {top, left, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
     x: left + width / 2,
     y: top + height / 2
   };
 }

function getDistanceBetweenElements(a, b) {
  const aPosition = getPositionAtCenter(a);
  const bPosition = getPositionAtCenter(b);

  return Math.hypot(aPosition.x - bPosition.x, aPosition.y - bPosition.y);  
}

const distance = getDistanceBetweenElements(
  document.getElementById("x"),
  document.getElementById("y")
);
console.log(distance)
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>

<div id="y" style="margin-left:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
            let current_item_children = $("div.sec").find('img');
            let children = [];
            $.each(current_item_children, function () {
                var this_item = $(this);
                children.push(
                    {
                    width: this_item.width(),
                    outerWidth:this_item.outerWidth(false),
                    height: this_item.height(),

                    }
                );
                console.log(children);
                });
        });
```

try this function